# Devise-jwt - No Authorization header is present in the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-jwt

I'm encountering an issue with my API-only Rails application. I attempted to set up token-based authentication using Devise and Devise-JWT, but it seems that I'm not receiving the Bearer token in my response when testing the API with Postman. I'm relatively new to Devise, tokens, and security in general. Could you offer some guidance and potential solutions for this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
  # devise.rb
  config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY']
    jwt.dispatch_requests = [['POST', /api/]]
    jwt.expiration_time = 12.hours.to_i
  end
```

```
    # routes.rb
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'api/sessions'
    }
  end
end
```

```
# api/sessions_controller.rb
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    user = User.find_by('lower(email) = ?', params[:email])

    if user.blank? || !user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json: {
        errors: ['Invalid email/password combination']
      }, status: :unauthorized
      return
    end

    sign_in(:user, user)

    render json: {
      user: user,
      token: user.token
    }
  end
```

```
    # user.rb
    # frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :validatable,
         :trackable,
         :jwt_authenticatable,
         jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenylist
end
```

```
   # jwt_denylist.rb
    class JwtDenylist < ApplicationRecord
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Denylist

  self.table_name = 'jwt_denylist'
end
```

```
# cors.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: %i[get post put patch delete options head]
  end
end
```